# Parse.com PHP SDK very really slow

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-platform

I've been researching both on Google and here on StackOverflow but still couldn't get a solid answer.

I'm developing a web app using Codeigniter and Parse.com to store my data.

However, their PHP SDK is extremely slow.

My queries are simple and my test database is really small with just a few records (5 classes with 3 or 4 rows each). Still, the queries take forever.. Sometimes more than 10 seconds.

I'm using it on my computer (local server) but I also uploaded to Bluehost to see if the problem was with my Internet and it's still really slow.

Anyone know what should I do to improve the performance? Or if the Javascript library would work faster?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do with your internet connection. it is just the parse php sdk, and don't use parse with php. I suggest use Node JS instead. or you can wait until parse come up with a better sdk version.

Comment: Thanks Ajit. I'm considering migrating to the JS library. For now I made a workaround using the REST api and curl on php.. It's still slow but not as slow. I want to finish the structure and the interface of my platform and then I will migrate it to Javascript.. It won't be a lot of work.